# Hyperledger Fabric - how to query about network artifacts, policies, chaincode etc

Tags: testing, hyperledger-fabric

My concern is if I have setup on different VMS.
Having specific channel for a pair of peers.

How and where to query information such as:

How many channels are their in the network? what are their names?
who can join (specific) channel?
which chaindode is part of a specific channel?
who has the right to initiate chaincode?
how to check if any peer does not have the right to initiate chaincode but is trying to?
how to check what happens while chaincode is running?
how to check if any peer is trying to join a channel that they should not join?

In general, how to query/select this information?

All commands that i have seen allow to invoke chaincode or join channel and so on. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use fabric SDK they are available in various languages, personally I am using node SDK or another option you can use [hyperledger/explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) to view all the activities in the network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean something like this: https://github.com/Altoros/fabric-rest/blob/master/REST.md . This is on node.js.

Comment: Also, can't Prometheus be enough? I am not sure about the difference between using Prometheus API and the above API. How are they same and different?

Comment: @Tarzan Yes REST API calls you will have full control over there. if you just want to monitor or observe the network then explorer is the best option.

Comment: I would like to suggest go through official SDK https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node on top of this you can build your own REST APIs